# What are the possible states for a docker container?

Tags: docker, states

Are there states other than "running", "paused" and "stopped" or are these the only states available?

Comment: check this link: https://medium.com/@nagarwal/lifecycle-of-docker-container-d2da9f85959

Answer (score 53, accepted):

No, there are other possible states. The [Docker Remote API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.21/) defines the following states:

- `created` A container that has been created (e.g. with `docker create`) but not started
- `restarting` A container that is in the process of being restarted
- `running` A currently running container
- `paused` A container whose processes have been paused
- `exited` A container that ran and completed ("stopped" in other contexts, although a `created` container is technically also "stopped")
- `dead` A container that the daemon tried and failed to stop (usually due to a busy device or resource used by the container) - [Added on v1.22](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.22/)

Comment: Not sure about Docker, but in Podman there's one more: `stopping`.

Answer (score 3):

[Docker Remote API 1.24](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/) defines one more state

- dead

Comment: You should have put that in your edit :) I'll update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Running

The container is actively running and performing its tasks.

> Paused

The container's processes have been paused, but the container is still in a running state.

> Restarting

The container is in the process of restarting after being stopped or encountering an error.

> Exited

The container has completed its execution and has stopped, typically after successfully running a command or task.

> Dead

The container has encountered an error and cannot be restarted. It is no longer running or available.