# docker ps shows empty list - although docker telling container exists

Tags: docker, docker-container

when calling **docker ps** the list is empty, although I got an id:
(`dcbb6aeaa06ba43fcb.....`)

*My steps:*

- **Step 1**: I created an image (`imagekommando`) of an running js.file:

  [image: docker images]
- **Step 2**: I created a container (in background) based on my image

  ```
  docker run -d --name containerkommando imagekommando
  ```

  [image: docker run -d --name containerkommando imagekommando]

  I got an id! (container-id??)
- **Step 3**: But `docker ps` shows empty list:

  [image: docker ps]

But when I repeat Step 2, I'm told, that the container (`containerkommando`) already exists:

```
docker run -d --name containerkommando imagekommando
```

[image: docker run -d --name containerkommando imagekommando]

Could you help me, understanding the logic behind?
And how can I get the container running (by ID)?

Comment: Your container probably exited. Try `docker ps -a`.

Comment: I solved the problem by installing nodemon

Comment: SOLVED: ...(npm install --save nodemon) which was listed in package.json. Then I rebuilt the image and run a new container based on the image  (docker run -d ...)!

Answer (score 2):

That means that the docker container exited with an error but clean up is required. With --rm option you can tell the docker to remove the container when the container has exited.

```
docker run --rm .....
```

Also to check the reason for the container exiting...you can use

```
docker logs <container_id>
```

Answer (score 2):

What probably takes place here:

1. `docker run ...` creates and starts your container
2. your container exits
3. `docker ps` doesn't list stopped containers (default shows just running), so it made you think that it's not there.
4. `docker run ...` fails because you are trying to create and run a container with a name that already exists.

Further reading:

- [What are the possible states for a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427684/what-are-the-possible-states-for-a-docker-container)
- [Why docker container exits immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212380/why-docker-container-exits-immediately)

Answer (score 1):

In Docker, a container is automatically exited when the task is finished. You have to specify a correct entrypoint to keep your docker container up.

You can check the exited containers with the command `docker ps -a`. This exited container will prevent you from using the name again.

So, you may want to use `docker rm <container-name>` before creating your new container. In a test environement, you can also use `docker system prune` to clean all unused container/networks.

Answer (score 0):

`docker ps` only shows the active containers (the running ones).

Your container most probably exited right after you started it. You can use the container ID and do `docker logs <container-id>` to examine the reason why the container failed.

If you want to see the stopped containers together with the running containers you can do `docker ps -a` to get a list of all these.

Answer (score 0):

Execute

```
docker logs <CONTAINER ID>
```

to view the logs of docker container run.

I faced a similar issue found out there was space issue win my docker. After clearing space the container was able to run.