# What happens to previous docker containers when you run its image one more time?

Tags: docker

I had a docker image and inside it, I had a container (a). I accidentally used the command 'docker run '. Now I cannot see container a anymore. Is it possible to access it? How can I do that?

Comment: `docker run` `creates` and `starts` a new container based on the `image` you specified. You can check the status of all the containers by using `docker container ls -a`. One place to start (which might make things more clear)  [What are the possible states for a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427684/what-are-the-possible-states-for-a-docker-container)

Comment: Thanks @tgogos. For those who are having the same problem, the answer is: no the container will not be removed or replaced. If you remember the container name, you can type docker start container-name and it will be listed in the docker ps items.